# Detecting type literals works in isolation but not when combined with other literal types

Tags: typescript

I have a series of type utilities which test whether a given type `<T>` is the literal or *wide* variant of the type:

- `IsStringLiteral<T extends string>`
- `IsNumericLiteral<T extends number>`
- `IsBooleanLiteral<T extends boolean>`

I then wanted to wrap these utilities into a single utility `IsLiteral` which looks like the following:

```
export type IsLiteral<T extends string | number | boolean> = T extends string
  ? IsStringLiteral<T>
  : T extends boolean
    ? IsBooleanLiteral<T>
    : T extends number
      ? IsNumericLiteral<T>
      : never;
```

I am running *type* tests on all of the individual utilities as well as my master blaster `IsLiteral` and everything works ... except I get a *false positive* for booleans when I test `IsLiteral<boolean>` and yet `IsBooleanLiteral<boolean>` works as expected.

You can find info on the `IsLiteral` here: [ [definition](https://github.com/inocan-group/inferred-types/blob/aeccf96938b644dff7c4b8b9c5bf694d571ea5dd/src/types/TypeInfo/IsLiteral.ts), [test](https://github.com/inocan-group/inferred-types/blob/aeccf96938b644dff7c4b8b9c5bf694d571ea5dd/tests/TypeInfo/IsLiteral.spec.ts) ]

Here's an inline version of the test which fails:

[image]

Comment: I imagine you've accidentally made your conditional types distributive, and the fix would be like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRXV1m), but without a self-contained [mre] I can't be sure.  Could you [edit] the question so that the code can be pasted as-is into a standalone IDE to demonstrate the issue, without requiring navigation to external sites?  Also 
[please supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)  If you do this and want me to take another look, please reply and mention @jcalz to notify me. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `boolean` is internally represented as `true | false`. That means it'll be distributed in this conditional:

```
  : T extends boolean
    ? IsBooleanLiteral<T>
```

and it'll now be:

```
(true extends boolean ? IsBooleanLiteral<true> : ...) | (false extends boolean ? IsBooleanLiteral<false> : ...)
```

which simplifies to:

```
IsBooleanLiteral<true> | IsBooleanLiteral<false>
```

both of which are `true`, so you get `true` for `boolean`. You can avoid this by wrapping it in a tuple. This is described in [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) in the handbook:

```
  : [T] extends [boolean]
    ? IsBooleanLiteral<T>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgZWAJwJYDsDmAZVwLICGANgDwAqUEAHvugCZxRwoaYB8UAvM61lbQgMmlAPxQAZiTjQAXFBQBXCAG4AsAChNoSLDgAhAPaHiEQulz4iZSjTqMoAI2OnznHs5Nn0A+yKjiUsQyUPJKqpra4NDwAHKKALYEqADGlgQkFL5CDuiJjgTuUHkJBcjZwlBiktJyCsjK6loaOjFw6dZZdjlMLGj8AD7F+QRQQ56u6EUA2uQAuhUO031sc5pQAXpI-Th4GTbs66FQswvdldMT3msaGxvi8EZe5h2Z5Ie3d-Kni0zTJWUbnc7g84PEkmg0ntOu8jsD5OgIAA3AhNKK6cgABgAjNw9K8yFc3E0APQku4APVE6OgWIATHjHi5vATSESpqTyRsqZogA)

Comment: very helpful comments and I will look more into the distributive conditional types as soon as I eat lunch. I did plug in your solution into the code however and it still fails in the same way.

Comment: @ken Fails in what way? At least in [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoAneN), it seems to be working as expected. Also, have a nice lunch.

Comment: Oh sorry, you know I didn't look at your playground just saw the reference inline ... let me look _before_ lunch :)

Comment: ok it does work! I just used the array wrapper for the boolean condition and not the others. I'll read up after lunch but I already have a working solution thanks to your help!